# Embedded .xib appearing in wrong position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, ios8

I was hoping this was an iOS 8 bug (it still might be; everything works fine in iOS 7) but I'm still seeing it in the iOS 8 GM Seed.

I have a CategoriesView.xib embedded in DetailView.xib. When the DetailView.xib is displayed, the placeholder UIView displays in the right location, but the contents of CategoriesView.xib appear exactly 72px above where they're supposed to. I'm using Autolayout. The 72px seems to be 20px status bar + 44px navigation bar + 8px auto layout constraint from the top of the image.

[image]

Inside CategoriesView.xib, there are actually 5 little icons representing each possible category. Each icon has a width/height constraint and a leading space constraint to add padding from its neighbor. Typically a screen will only show 1-2 categories, and I accomplish this with this code:

```
// all width constraints are part of the categoryViewsWidthConstraints Outlet Collection
// all padding constraints are part of the categoryViewsSpacingConstraints Outlet Collection

// loop through my outlet collection, and set all width and padding constraints to 0
for (int i = 0; i < self.categoryViewsWidthConstraints.count; i++) {
    [self.categoryViewsWidthConstraints[i] setConstant:0.0];
    [self.categoryViewsSpacingConstraints[i] setConstant:0.0];
}

// now, for the categories that need to show, add the width and padding constraints back
for (int i = 0; i < self.categoryIds.count; i++) {
    NSNumber *categoryId = self.categoryIds [i];
    [self.categoryViewsWidthConstraints[categoryId.integerValue - 1] setConstant:20.0];
    [self.categoryViewsSpacingConstraints[categoryId.integerValue - 1] setConstant:8.0];
}
```

Again, this works fine in iOS 7.

I thought I had this working when, inside CategoriesView.m, I set:

```
self.contentView.translatesAutoResizingMaskintoConstraints = true.
```

That gives me the correct vertical placement I'm after, but unfortunately I get auto layout errors because it thinks CategoriesView needs to be exactly 132px wide. Because of this, the last category icon gets stretched:

[image]

I'm at a loss here. I know this is pretty nuanced, but any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything I could think of, and just could not get this to work.

My solution? I simply created a brand new file and reconstructed all the elements and all the constraints. And it worked perfectly.

So so frustrating, but things are finally back to normal. I think it had something to do with the transition from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6.